# Pymongo Nested Search

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some nested data in mongo that I am trying (unsuccessfully) to query. An example of the document I am trying to find is shown below:

```
{
    'T009_Measurments': {
        'ConditionKey': 'WPS-ActivePower 0-920,',
        'HalfLifeDays': 100,
        'ID': 120,
        'LocationName': 'T001',
        'MeasurementKey': 'Some DATA/LOC/LOC LOC/FFT_16000',
        'Overload': 0,
        'RPM': 1496.6044,
        'RedAlarm': 0,
        'TimeClosed-Min': 1440,
        'Trigger_Time': datetime.datetime(2099, 6, 11, 20, 20, 40),
        'WPS-ActivePower-Average': 727.0,
        'WPS-ActivePower-Deviation': 0.0,
        'YellowAlarm': 0
    }
}
```

What I really want to do is search by HalfLifeDays. I have tried several things including:

```
db.collection.find({'T009_Measurments.HalfLifeDays' : 100})
db.collection.find({'T009_Measurments'}: {'HalfLifeDays' : 100})
```

But so far I cannot get anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The fist one seems find to me, is there any error message?

Comment: The code executes with no error message, however no data is returned. When I do a count I get 0.

Comment: Do you get the right count of documents when using `db.collection.count()`?

Comment: Yes. Everything seems to be fine there.

Comment: Did you enter the name of your collection correctly? In the given sample it just says `collection`

Comment: I do have the correct collection name specified... I am going to look a little more closely at the structure of the document... I think I may be missing something.

Comment: I have now successfully queried using the find method and searching by id. So I don't think my structure is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Like many problems this can be attributed to user error. I had some incorrect references in my query. I only discovered this when in pure desperation I copied the key from:
`Object.keys(db.collectionName.findOne())`

and pasted it into my query. Then everything worked fine. Thank you all that provided some trouble shooting advice.